# android package dependency download via api command

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am really new to android dev (C/Python engineer), and I am looking to include a package from github where it says download the package [using](https://natario1.github.io/CameraView/about/install.html):

```
api 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.0.0-beta04'
```

I have spent 2 hours looking WTF this `api` tool is but for the life of me, I cannot seem to figure out what it is.

My dependency block looks like so:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.0.0-beta04'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

As you see, I have added the:

```
implementation 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.0.0-beta04'
```

and synced the project with gradle files and I still get unresolved reference

Comment: You're supposed to put it in the dependencies block of the build.gradle file for the app module. It's not a command line tool, it's a Gradle function

Comment: @Zoe: REALLY appreciate your comment - but in my build.gradle I already have `implementation 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.0.0-beta04'` should I add the `api ..` in addition to this?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. After compile was deprecated and split into implementation and api (and maybe another one? I don't remember), I never saw the point of api. Seemed like implementation covered most of those cases. If you get an unresolved reference though, do you have the repositories added? Specifically jcenter for this dependency

Comment: Zoe: thanks again. I have jcenter on the main gradle file. One question: how do I import this dependency in the mainactivity file? How do I know what path I should use to import? Again, googling doesn't help!

Comment: Java doesn't actually import by path, like the languages you mentioned. It imports by package and class name, so you add `import com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView;` (if you're not after the CameraView class, change the class to the one you're looking for) at the top (after the package statement, and before class declaration). That assumes the gradle build succeeds on the import though - if the unresolved reference is with the package download, the issue is elsewhere. (I hope this is what you're asking - if it isn't, tell me)

Comment: Although if that's the unresolved reference, it sounds more like a linking issue. If you can't build via the command line either, try to delete the .gradle folder in the project, and/or file -> invalidate caches and restart in Android Studio.

Comment: Zoe: I deleted everything and started all over again, but now, I copy some sample code and paste it on the mainactivity and it complains the code is in Java and not Kotlin. the whole android ecosystem sucks.

Comment: Is the file a Java file or a Kotlin file? (if it has classes without `public` and has some Activity after a `:` after the class name, it's Kotlin). If that's the case, you'll need to re-create the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192489/discussion-between-ajw-and-zoe).

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation try to add:

```
api 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.7.2'
```

For more information visit, https://github.com/natario1/CameraView